# How to check if sqlite table empty extract result

Tags: python, sqlite

I am checking if a table in my database is empty. I cannot get the value that the sql statement returns to be usable.

The section of the code is as follows :

```
with sqlite3.connect("BENSBIGDATABASE.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) from login ''')
    result=cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
    if result == 0 :
        print("is 0")
    else :
        print("is not 0 ")
```

The output that the code is producing is :

```
[(0,)]
is not 0
```

I am returning the correct result however the if statement is not working underneath. From what I understand this is because of the brackets around it?

Comment: Seems a bit overkill to count all elements for a empty check. But I guess that's the way. How about: `SELECT COUNT(*) from login LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result from `fetchall` is a list of tuples.

Your result should contain one tuple, which would contain one number, which is the row count.

```
if result[0][0]==0:
    print("is zero")
else:
    print("is not zero")
```

Comment: ahh that makes sense Thanks